# QML Why Window.requestUpdate() is not working?

Tags: qt, qml, window, redraw

I have a Qt Quick Window:

```
Window{
   id: mainWindow
   ...
}
```

I want to display a message box before a long blocking operation in QML:

```
// Set visible=true of 'messageBox' Rectangle{}
messageBox.showWaitMessage("Please wait")

// I want to show it before blocked the screen
mainWindow.requestUpdate()

// Long blocking operation:
compressFile("filepath")
```

All the objects in the screen are children of `mainWindow`.

---

But it is not working. It stills not redrawing the screen before the blocking operation.

Why?

Comment: Probably your `compressFile` blocks the GUI thread. You should run a long operation in a separate thread.

Comment: I know it blocks. This is why I want to refresh the screen just before it blocks :)

Comment: No, you _request_ updating, not really updated the GUI.

Comment: Yes that is why it is not working +1, I thought it is(requestUpdate) forcing screen to update immediately.

Comment: Anyway, the GUI programming requires that the main thread will not be blocked by user. Moreover you have tools to run your task in a separate thread - either WorkerScript in QML or QThread in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your function which invokes those calls is not finished yet and the `requestUpdate()` which is queued to be executed by the event loop will actually happen after `compressFile`.
This is a sign of bad design and it's better to move your compressFile to another thread. If threading is not an option, you may want to call `compressFile` indirectly like this, which will put that call into the queue. Then the GUI eventloop will repaints the widget before the timer slot being executed. You do not need to update GUI manually.

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, [=]() { compressFile("filepath") } );
```

This is only possible for Qt5.4 and above because of [QTBUG-26406](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26406).
If you are using a lower version of Qt you can do the same thing like:

```
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
       compressFile("filepath");
       timer->deleteLater();
    } );
    timer->start(0);
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I've searching for, but it gives another way to solve it :+1: . Actually I thought mainWindow.requestUpdate() is similiar to repaint() in C++ side. So thanks anyway :)

Comment: How do you use thread with QML?

Comment: @Bersan GUI has it's own thread. So, if you want to use threads in a QML app you have two options. 1- Qt Concurrent module which is quite mature and you can easily implement resource intensive tasks on c++ side and interact with your working threads using signals and slots. 2- you can also use ```WorkerScript``` QML type which is not always a good option but if you want to write in JS and run on a separate thread, it's also an option.